# capture the id of the process which called the function inside the function

Tags: shell-script

I want to log the ID of the process which called a specific function in Korn shell scripting.

eg Lets consider an user-defined autoload function SQUARE.
Now if a TestSquare.sh script calls SQUARE function. I want to capture the process id of the TestSquare.sh in execution and the start time of the TestSquare.sh process.

I do not want to pass any parameters to the fucntion. I want to construct all the information by using just the process id of the calling script.

Comment: I donot want to pass the process ID to the function. thanks for the reply mikeserv

Comment: shouldn't I be calling "SQUARE 4 $$" to capture the process id of TestSquare.sh in execution and then inside the SQUARE function use $2 to play with the process ID.SQUARE is a autoload function sitting in another file. How can I leverage $$ here. Would it get a different process id?

Comment: SQUARE is a autoload function sitting in another file.

Comment: I tried it just now Mike. It worked . I am really sorry . I was under and impression that the function will spawn as different process. I ran few foreground and background checks . This works amazing. Thank you so much. I am a little new to this scripting.

Comment: I am trying to make a logging framework for which I intend to pass just the message and rest it has to configure itself in the function, the standard log name, time, folder to log etc

Answer (score 3):

The process ID of the shell is available in the special parameter `$$` (in the ksh manual, this is documented under the section “Parameter expansion”).

```
log () {
  printf "script=%s pid=%d message=%s\n" "$0" "$$" "$1"
}
```

Note that `$$` is the process ID of the script. If you execute code in a subshell (i.e. in parentheses, inside a command substitution, on the left-hand side of a pipe, etc.), that doesn't change the value of `$$`. If you want the process ID that actually emitted the log message, you can get it by calling a subprocess and telling it to report its parent process ID. (Some shells have a variable for that, but I think not ATT ksh.)

```
log () {
  printf "script=%s script_pid=%d emitting_pid=%d message=%s\n" \
         "$0" "$$" "$(sh -c 'echo $PPID')" "$1"
}
```

If you want to log the script's starting time, the easiest way would be to assign the current time to a variable when the script starts.

```
#!/bin/ksh
start_time=$(date)
```

If you need to get the script's starting time later, you can get it with `ps -o stime`, but that doesn't give you the full date and time. Alternatively, you can calculate from the variable `SECONDS` (which always contains the number of seconds since the script was started) and the current date. If you're using ksh, you probably don't have GNU date, which leaves you without convenient tools for date calculations. Awk provides a roundabout way to get the number of seconds since the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so the following snippet sets `start_time` to the script's starting time in seconds since the epoch:

```
start_time=$(export SECONDS; awk 'BEGIN {srand(); print srand() - ENVIRON["SECONDS"]; exit}')
```